# Grails & Vaadin plugin - how to get latest version of Vaadin?

Tags: grails, vaadin, grails-plugin

I am using this plugin http://www.grails.org/plugin/vaadin and the plugin supports only Vaadin version 6.5.1.

1. Is there any way how to upgrade Vaadin version to the latest one (e.g. 6.7.3)?
2. And maybe even more, is it anyhow possible to use Vaadin 7 (7.0.0-aplha...) together with Grails-Vaadin plugin? I know it is not stable release, but it would be great to start working with that version.

Comment: I have send a request here: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPVAADIN-8 but it seems that none is working on that project...

Comment: You can do the following hack: locate the plugin POM file (or parent POM, if relevant) in your local repository and in that POM change the version of Vaadin to one you need, then do `mvn install` as usual. But it is not clear, how Vaadin version in maven plugin affects your application? Please, explain.

Comment: I'm not using Maven in my project. Yarovoy's answer is the correct one. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could checkout the plugin's sources or download it as a zip-file, extract and then include it as inplace plugin into your project:

```
// Add in BuildConfig.groovy of your project.
grails.plugin.location.vaadin = '../path/to/vaadin'
```

After that you could do any manipulations to upgrading the plugin to required version of Vaadin.

Comment: If anyone wants, you can use this (grails 2.0.0 and vaadin 6.7.4): https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded Vaadin and Grails to the latest version. I have not found how to do it officially, so I have put it to my github profile, feel free to use it: https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin/downloads

Comment: Version 1.5.4 specifies Vaadin 6.3, not 6.8